# take output of row update with stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-update

I want to update a row using stored procedure. Even if I am able to update row, I can not pass affected rows count into my 'OUT' value. Here:

[image]

Comment: I moved your image inline but you're going to need to add some details (like code) and a better example of what you want to see

Comment: Thanks but there is no need for extra code for this question.